# Python Tryiing to verify if argv is an int?

Tags: python

Here is my code but fails because argv is an object:
I am trying to run a python prgram from command line with the int included
EX: `python3 test.py 7`

`test.py` contains:

```
text = input("Enter some text:")
code = argv[1]
if not code.isdigit():
    exit()
```

Comment: What does the read from stdin have to do with this, since you're checking content from the command line?

Comment: ...see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- code examples should be minimal, thus not including anything unrelated to reproducing the problem at hand. In this particular case, that means the `text = input("Enter some text:")` line probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: Try this `if type(var) is int:`

Comment: @smokehill, `argv` entries will always be strings from a type-system perspective, so that's always false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is `sys.argv`, not `argv`. You thus need to import the `sys` module. (You could also `from sys import argv`, or -- worse -- `from sys import *` -- but don't).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
code = sys.argv[1]
if not code.isdigit():
    exit()
```

It's also common practice to simply try casting your string to an integer, and catch the place where that fails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
code = sys.argv[1]
try:
    code_int = int(code)
except ValueError, e:
    print("Unable to parse code as an integer")
    sys.exit(1)
print("Parsed code as {}".format(code_int))
```

...which has the advantage of putting an integer version of your value in `code_int`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use argparse instead to force an integer input and checking of numbers

```
import argparse

text = input("Enter some text:")
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some integers.')
parser.add_argument('code', metavar='N', type=int, help='an integer')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

alternativly you can use cli-args-system, it converts automatcly everthing to numbers(float or int)
install:

```sh
linux: pip3 install cli-args-system
windows: pip install cli-args-system
```

```py
from cli_args_system import Args

args = Args()
print(args.args())
```

```sh
python3  teste.py 10 15.4 afd 
-> [10, 15.4, 'afd']
```